# Rounding double value for currency

Tags: java, android, double, bigdecimal

Having a lot of trouble rounding a value to display in a textView.

I basically wanna round it to two decimal places but at the moment I am getting a long trail of different numbers.

I am playing around with BigDecimal but no luck so far...

```
public void calc() {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(subTotal);
        bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
        total.setText(String.valueOf(bd));
    }
```

Comment: Don't use floating-point values to represent currency! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

Comment: That sort of worked but when I kept adding I eventually got the trailing zeros again..any idea ?

Comment: Maybe you should always format it before displaying it!!

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(subTotal);
bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
total.setText(String.valueOf(bd));
// Input: 9.888888 -> Output: 9.89
// Input: 9f -> Output: 9.00
```